# Reduce JavaScript array to matching elements with counts

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I've got a nested array:

```
// 3rd element in sub-array indicates a number of repeats
var list = [["a","b",1],["a","d",1],["a","b",1],["c","d",1]];
```

Task is to remove identical sub-arrays and increase number in single unique sub-array, which would indicate the number of repeats, so that above example would transform into smth like:

```
[["a","b",2],["a","d",1],["c","d",1]]
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Currently I'm trying smth like this:

```
var list = new Array();

// Sort by second element
list.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a[1] > b[1];
});

function collateList(element,index,array){
    // if 1st&2nd element of subarray equals to 1st&2nd element of next subarray
    if (array[index[0]]==array[index[0]+1] && array[index[1]]==array[index[1]+1]){
        // increase 3rd element of subarray by 1
        array[index[2]] = array[index[2]+1];
        // remove next element from an array
        array.splice((index+1),1);
    } 
}

list.forEach(collateList);
```

Comment: Is this a homework? Do you have any specific problem in doing that?

Comment: How about some inefficient solution first?

Comment: Not a homework, more like a general interest linked to a real problem. Consider the fact that there could be several million sub-arrays and processing time is very important. I'm interested in the most efficient function/algorithm to find and eliminate identical records, meahnwhile indicating the number of repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first define the function determining if two subarrays are to be combined, in this case that their first two values are the same:

```
function match(e1, e2) { return e1[0]===e2[0] && e1[1]===e2[1]; }
```

Now let us define a function which finds a matching element in an array, based on a matching function, and returns its index. This is the same as [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), were it defined.

```
function find(a, v, fn) {
    for (i in a) { if (fn(v, a[i])) {return i;} }
    return -1;
}
```

Now we feed the input through a `reduce` to create an new array with counts updated and duplicates removed:

```
list.reduce(                                  // Boil down array into a result
    function(result, elt) {                   // by taking each element
        var prev = find(result, elt, match);  // and looking for it in result so far.
        if (prev !== -1) {                    // If found
            result[prev][2]++;                // increment previous occurrence;
        } else {                              // otherwise
            result.push(elt);                 // include as is in the result.
        }
        return result;                        // Use this result for next iteration.
    }, 
    []                                        // Start off with an empty array.
)
```